# Switch is not properly working in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a switch statement which has several cases. These cases compare values and assign a text to a variable. But when I try to execute this switch, it always executes the default case. But my condition is true.. Why?

**Here is my value**

```
Apartment
```

**Here is my code**

```
var rental_cat = $('#rentals_type').val();
alert(rental_cat);
var rental_type = "";
switch (rental_cat) {
case (rental_cat == "Apartment"): 
    rental_type='daily';
    alert(rental_type);
    break;
case (rental_cat == "Office"):
    rental_type='work_daily';
    alert(rental_type);
    break;
default:
    rental_type='other';
    alert(rental_type);
    break;
}
```

When I execute this switch, it always gives me "**other**"

Comment: javascript switch syntax you got dont seem correct: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the conditional expression inside the "case" clause.

Try this:

```
var rental_cat = $('#rentals_type').val();

    alert(rental_cat);

    var rental_type = "";

    switch (rental_cat) {

    case "Apartment": 
                                        rental_type='daily';
                                        alert(rental_type);
                                        break;

    case "Office":
                                        rental_type='work_daily';
                                        alert(rental_type);
                                        break;

    default:
                                        rental_type='other';
                                        alert(rental_type);
                                        break;
}
```

Comment: @AshishVyas maybe you need to [trim()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) the input?

Comment: Hi @AshishVyas, it's working for me. You can check here https://jsfiddle.net/pablodarde/wg1wdcd7/

Comment: Thanks a lot @Thomas. after trim() that result, it works :)

Answer (score 0):

```
switch (rental_cat) {
  case (rental_cat == "Apartment"):
```

is equivalent to

```
switch (rental_cat) {
  case true:
```

which in turn is equivalent to

```
if (rental_cat === true)
```

You don't put a condition in the `case`, the condition is created as an equality check between the `switch` and the `case`s, so it should be like this instead:

```
switch (rental_cat) {
  case "Apartment":
```

Answer (score 0):

a switch is not the right structure to deal with this problem. Here I'd recommend a map:

```
var rentalTypesByCat = {
    DEFAULT:        "other",

    "Apartement":   "daily",
    "Office":       "work_daily",
}

var rental_cat = $('#rentals_type').val();
console.log("rental_cat:", rental_cat);

var rental_type = rentalTypesByCat[rental_cat] || rentalTypesByCat.DEFAULT;
console.log("rental_type:", rental_type);
```

or if you need it a bit more explicit (for example because some of your mapped values may be falsy themselves):

```
var rental_type = rentalTypesByCat[rental_cat in rentalTypesByCat? rental_cat: "DEFAULT"];
console.log("rental_type:", rental_type);
```